# MUI Datagrid | Server Paging - Paging arrows are disabled

Tags: reactjs, mui-x-data-grid

I'm creating a basic page with a MUI datagrid Pager with server paging. After loading the rows on first load, the next paging arrow is disabled.

**UI Setup**
"react": "^17.0.2" | "@mui/x-data-grid": "^6.6.0"

This is my function component (I used a class component intially but it had no change in result)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { DataGrid } from "@mui/x-data-grid";

const TestPager = (props) => {

  const [customers, setCustomers] = useState([]);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [pageSize, setPageSize] = useState(2);
      
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCustomers = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(`/api/paged-list?page=${page}&pageSize=${pageSize}`);
      const data = await response.json();

      setCustomers(data.Data);
      setPage(data.Page);
      setPageSize(data.PageSize);
    };

    fetchCustomers();
  }, [page, pageSize]);

  const paginationFunction = async (params) => {
    const response = await fetch(`/api/paged-list?page=${params.page}&pageSize=${params.pageSize}`);
    const data = await response.json();

    setCustomers(data.Data);
    return {
      rows: data.Data,
      pageCount: 3
    };
  };

  const columns = [
    { field: "Id", headerName: "ID" },
    { field: "Name", headerName: "Name" }
  ];

  return (
      <>
          <div id="loadSpinners" style={{ height: "8px" }}></div>
          <DataGrid
              rows={customers}
              columns={columns}
              paginationMode="server"
              rowCount={6}
              getRowId={(row) => row.Id}
              paginationFunction={paginationFunction}
              onPaginationModelChange={(c) => {
                setPage(c.page);
                setPageSize(c.pageSize);
              }}
          />
      </>
      
  );
};

export default TestPager;
```

**BackEnd Api**
.Net 6 returning dummy data

https://.../api/paged-list?page=3&pageSize=2

**Problem**
I'm getting data into the grid on initial load, but the next paging arrow is disabled.
For e.g.
[image]

**What I've tried**
Followed this [link](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/pagination/#basic-implementation), the same result happens - Pager arrows are disabled.
I've also asked Google Bard/Chat GPT and followed the example they gave. The same result happens.

What am I missing? I think it's most likely something small.

Comment: I fixed this by downgrading to  "@mui/x-data-grid": "^5.11.1"

The pager arrows work now. For reference, I followed this guys project

https://github.com/abhidiwakar/mui_data_grid_ssp